# Convert Excel formula into SQL query

Tags: mysql, excel-formula

I am rather new to SQL but enthusiastic and willing to learn. I have am running an SQL query successfully so far however i am stuck on the below and hoping you can help, its a little too complex for me kowledge.
I have an Excel formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Sourced from internal",A1)-1),":",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

This is extracting a text string from a large cell of data containing text, numbers, dates.
It works perfectly in Excel however i'm lost where to start converting this to a working SQL function on a field named 'PRODSUMMARY' within my DB. Can anyone assist please?

I tried to experiment using a few similar posts however i am getting an error message.

Below is the data pulled into the PRODSUMMARY field, and what I achieve with the Excel:

```
PROACTIVE: SEV 1
INCIDENT START TIME: 01/17/2021 14:25:04
ID: urgent-abc12345-6789101f011
ALT ID: ABC-12345-000-F011
PRODUCT: NETWORK
EQUIPMENT TYPE: NETWORK DEVICE
INCIDENT TYPE: NETWORK ISSUE ABC-12345-000-F011: Network Loss SOURCED FROM INTERNAL MONITORING SYSTEM
MONITORING ALARM ID: ABCDE-1234BND56RMRMWRTE
TEXT: Device is inaccessible for monitoring
```

Expected result of formula: extract the incident type wording. For example in the above I would only want to extract "Network Loss"
The constant would be "SOURCED FROM INTERNAL MONITORING SYSTEM" and the location of the colons.

I need to extract wording after the 2nd colon and before the word Sourced, the word/s will be variable lengths depending on the incident type being reported.

Kind regards

Benny

Comment: Just to be clear, your database is a mysql server?

Comment: Yes correct JNevill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by creatuoing a table and checking the manual for commands that correspond

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(mytext TEXT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ("PROACTIVE: SEV 1
> INCIDENT START TIME: 01/17/2021 14:25:04
> ID: urgent-abc12345-6789101f011
> ALT ID: ABC-12345-000-F011
> PRODUCT: NETWORK
> EQUIPMENT TYPE: NETWORK DEVICE
> INCIDENT TYPE: NETWORK ISSUE ABC-12345-000-F011: Network Loss SOURCED FROM INTERNAL MONITORING SYSTEM
> MONITORING ALARM ID: ABCDE-1234BND56RMRMWRTE
> TEXT: Device is inaccessible for monitoring
> ")
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> TRIM(
>   RIGHT(
>       REPLACE(
>           LEFT(mytext,locate("Sourced from internal",mytext)-1)
>       ,":",SPACE(100)
>       ) 
> ,100)
> ) sometext
> FROM mytable;
> ```
>
> ```
> | sometext     |
> | :----------- |
> | Network Loss |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c735383e23d667cc40a69ce5f6c5c646)*

Answer (score 0):

In other languages this could be done directly with a regular expression. In MySQL a regex will only get us so far.

Starting with

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(`PRODSUMMARY`,'INCIDENT TYPE:.*?:\s*(.*?)\s*SOURCED')

We get `INCIDENT TYPE: NETWORK ISSUE ABC-12345-000-F011: Network Loss SOURCED`

From that we can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get to the second colon and space:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REGEXP_SUBSTR(`PRODSUMMARY`,'INCIDENT TYPE:.*?:\s*(.*?)\s*SOURCED'),': ',-1)
```

So now we have 'Network Loss SOURCED'

`TRIM` the trailing ' SOURCED'

```
SELECT trim(TRAILING ' SOURCED' FROM 
  substring_index(
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(`PRODSUMMARY`,'INCIDENT TYPE:.*?:\s*(.*?)\s*SOURCED'),': ',-1)) 
  as incidentText from `myTable`
```

Using a regular expression for the initial search allows for variable text to appear before the target items.